# Rails - redirecting to previous page properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

In my application I am trying to enforce that users be signed in to preform certain actions. And when they try to preform these actions when not signed, they are redirected to the 'Sign-In' page, and once they have signed in, they are redirected back to the page they were trying to access. I have all of this working properly with the below code.

**Controllers Code**

```
if !(signed_in?)
  session[:return_to] = newcompany_path
  redirect_to signin_path
  flash[:notice] = "You must be signed in to add companies."
else
      @company = Company.new
  @primary_field = @@fields
end

...

redirect_path = session[:return_to]
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    sign_in user
    session[:return_to] = nil
    if (redirect_path == nil)
      redirect_to user
    else
      redirect_to redirect_path
    end
else
```

The issue I am running into is, if the user clicks away from the sign-in page without actually signing in, the `session[return_to]` variable is not cleared properly, and if they then go back to sign in later, they are redirected to the wrong page.

So, how would I set it up so if the user clicks away from the sign-in page, the session[:redirect_to] variable is reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the `return_to` path in query string parameter rather than the session and submit it alongside the sign in form so that it only applies for that form, rather than subsequent requests.

When redirecting to the sign in form, it'd look like:

```
redirect_to signin_path(return_to: newcompany_path)
```

Then, in your sign in form, make sure to include a hidden field with the `return_to` value, like:

```
hidden_field_tag :return_to, params[:return_to]
```

Then in your controller action for signing in, you'll check `params[:return_to]` rather than `session[:return_to]` to get the path you want.

Comment: This is beautiful! Thanks a ton. Works perfectly. I havent worked with query string parameters before, do you by any chance know of any place to get some more knowledge on this stuff?

Comment: There's nothing particularly special about them. You can pretty much set any keys/values you want (though you have to be careful about using special characters like ? and & in the value) and then they'll be available to the server on the request. So if you go to a URL like /foo?bar=1&baz=rails, in Rails, you'll have params named `bar` and `baz`. When you generate a path in Rails, any keys of the hash that Rails does not recognize (id, anchor, etc.) will be turned into the query string. So `signin_path(return_to: newcompany_path)` would get you a URL like /signin?return_to=/companies/new

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
redirect_to request.referrer
```